# Proving formula for number of orbits of a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a finite set $S$. For $g \in G$ we
>   let $S^g := \{s \in S : g \cdot s = s\}$ and $S/G$ be the set of all
>   orbits. Then $$|S/G| = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} |S^g|$$

My task is to prove this first for the special case where $G$ acts on the set $G/H$ where $H \leq G$ by $g \cdot (xH) = gxH$. For that we introduce $$E:=\{(g,k)\in G \times G : k^{-1}gk \in H\}$$ And I have already proven that $$|E| = |G||H| \qquad \text{and} \qquad |E| = \sum_{g \in G} |(G/H)^g||H|$$ For me, this would imply $$1 = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} |(G/H)^g|$$ and so I would have to show that $$|(G/H)/G| = 1$$ which is equivalent to that there exists only one orbit. For me this does somehow make no sense.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? Of course there is only one orbit. Every (left) coset lies in the orbit of $H$ by definition of a coset.

Comment: Somehow I did not "intuitively" expected this...but I think it was almost too obvious at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems alright to me. The conclusion that the set of orbits for this action is a singleton is perfectly correct; indeed, every coset $xH\in G/H$ lies in the orbit of $1H$, as $xH=x\cdot 1H$. Thus the only orbit is that of $1H$. By the way, an action where there is only one orbit is called *transitive*.